# ant scp task not working for ear

Tags: ant

I am trying to scp my local ear to a remote server by using ant scp task. When I am trying to scp one single file this is working fine.
But when I am trying to scp ear it just displaying "[scp] Connecting to 192.168.1.44:22" But no response at all.

These are my 2 ant targets,

1.)

```
<target name="copy_to_remote_folder">
    <scp todir="krish@192.168.1.44:/test/jboss-4.0.3SP1/server/default/deploy" password="123456" port="22">
        <fileset dir="${ant.local.ear.dir}/testPro.war"/>
    </scp>
<target>
```

2.)

```
<target name="copy_to_remote_file">
    <scp file="${ant.local.ear.dir}/test.xml" todir="krish@192.168.1.44:/test/jboss-4.0.3SP1/server/default/deploy" password="123456"/>
</target>
```

copy_to_remote_file target is working fine and the copy_to_remote_folder is not working.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

A WAR or EAR is a single file.  This line...

```
<fileset dir="${ant.local.ear.dir}/testPro.war"/>
```

... doesn't make sense.  The `dir` attribute should be used to specify a path, the base path that contains the files you are including in the set.  Instead you are pointing it to a specific file.  Try this...

```
<target name="copy_to_remote_folder">
  <scp todir="krish@192.168.1.44:/test/jboss-4.0.3SP1/server/default/deploy" password="123456" port="22">
    <fileset dir="${ant.local.ear.dir}">
      <include name="*.war" />
    </fileset>
  </scp>
<target>
```

... or just use your copy_to_remote_file target.